# js: <input> field seems to be in memory twice after removing and re-adding to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I have an `<input>` element in html, inside a button:

HTML:

```
<button class="green button " id="playPause"> &nbsp;Play in&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" 
 id="timeInputInButton" maxlength="3" size="2" value="3" 
 style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:1px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:2px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px;" > 
 sec </button>
```

and in JS:

```
const timeInput = document.getElementById('timeInputInButton');
```

Now everythings works as expected: When I now say `timeInput.value = 100` the displayed value jumps to `100`.

But as soon as I remove the `timeInput`from the DOM and then (later) add it back again, it bahaves as if I had 2 `<input>`elements with the same `ìd`.

That's how I remove the element (even though it's the same if I use `.removeChild()`):

```
const playPauseButton = document.getElementById('playPause');
playPauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
```

And how I re-add it (doesn't matter if I use `appendChild`or `append`):

```
playPauseButton.appendChild(timeInput);
```

Now if I say `timeInput.value = 100` the GUI doesn't update.

`timeInput.value` = 100, but

`document.getElementById('timeInputInButton').value` returns the default value the input field had at the time of the variable binding `const timeInput = document.getElementById('timeInputInButton');`

Why does it look like I have 2 `<input>` elements in memory?

Comment: When using `removeChild`, are you storing the result? If you assign the return value to something, the element will stay in memory. Did you try without assigning it?

Comment: this is undoubtedly related to the fact that _interactive content_ is not allowed within a `<button>` element. Although the browser allows this and does what it can to make the flawed encapsulation work, using HTML inappropriately has consequences. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: Ok whatever, then I take the input out of the button. @RandyCasburn would you be so kind as to copy your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undoubtedly related to the fact that interactive content is not allowed within a `<button>` element. Although the browser allows this and does what it can to make the flawed encapsulation work, using HTML inappropriately has consequences.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)